# type 'IReportServerCredentials' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

Currently i'm using VS2015 to develop web application.

I facing the issue after i adding the "**Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms**" & "**Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common**" version 11.0.0.0 cause the 52 same error as same as the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADZss.png)

**CS0012**
The type 'IReportServerCredentials' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

&

**CS0266**
Cannot implicitly convert type 'BulkServicesReports.UI.Process.SSRSCredentials' to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QREHk.png)

and here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>


  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="General Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="log\General.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="DAC Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="log\DAC.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="BC Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="log\BC.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="Servcies Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="log\services.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="Reports Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="\log\Reports.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="Unprocessed Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" fileName="log\Unprocessed.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral" template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}" name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="General Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="DAC">
        <listeners>
          <add name="DAC Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="BC">
        <listeners>
          <add name="BC Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Services">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Servcies Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Reports">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Reports Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Unprocessed Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="General Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    <add key="WarningDB" value="Unable to retrieve data! Please contact your administrator." />
    <add key="WarningService" value="Unable to communicate with services! Please contact your administrator." />
    <add key="WarningGeneral" value="Unable to perform the operation! Please contact your administrator." />
    <add key="ReportViewerUser" value="devsupport" />

    <add key="ReportViewerDomain" value="" />

    <!--<add key="ReportServer" value="http://localhost/ReportServer"/>-->
    <add key="QRTransDetails" value="/QRTransDetails.aspx" />
    <add key="QRTrackDetails" value="/QRTrackDetails.aspx" />

    <!-- For Service Country ID Reporting-->
    <add key="USSDServCountryID" value="195" />
    <add key="PremiumUSSDServCountryID" value="208" />
    <add key="QRCodeInformationServCountryID" value="196" />
    <add key="QRCodeMobileMarketingServCountryID" value="197" />
    <add key="NetworkQueryServCountryID" value="193" />
    <add key="MNPQueryServCountryID" value="194" />
    <add key="PremiumMMSServCountryID" value="201" />
    <add key="DCBServCountryID" value="209,217,240" />
    <add key="IndiaDCBCountryID" value="217" />
    <add key="ReportingID" value="210" />
    <add key="CimbKwikServCountryID" value="215" />
    <add key="SouthAfricaPremiumSMSServCountryID" value="202" />
    <!-- For Service ID Reporting-->
    <add key="MMSServID" value="22" />
    <add key="OneNetService" value="211,218,219,220,221,222,213,223,224,225,226,227,214,228,229,230,231,232" />
    <add key="PremiumSMSServiceID" value="3" />
    <add key="Domain" value="MKAdmin" />
    <add key="Application" value="MPReport" />

    <add key="DCBCountry" value="17-India,2-Singapore,3-Thailand,1-Malaysia" />
    <add key="2DCBTelco" value="1-Singtel" />
    <add key="3DCBTelco" value="3-AIS,5-CAT" />
    <add key="4DCBTelco" value="4-Celcom"/>
    <add key="CountryListID" value="1-Malaysia,2-Singapore,3-Thailand,&#xD;&#xA;         4-Indonesia,5-Brunei,6-Hong Kong,7-Taiwan,8-Vietnam,9-Philippines,&#xD;&#xA;         10-Australia,11-South Africa,12-China,13-USA,14-Russia,&#xD;&#xA;         15-Saudi Arabia,16-New Zealand,17-India,18-Myanmar" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"><controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls></pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpUserService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBroadcastLogService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="basicHttpQRCodeService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpPUSSDService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpAdminService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpDCBService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpStatusHelpService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpStatusService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpCountryService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpClientService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpTelcoService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpScratchCardDetailsService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpScratchCardSummaryService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpCimbKwikService" />
        <binding name="basicHttpBoldSummaryService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="basicHttpSSRSReportConfigService" />
        <binding name="HttpAccessControlService" />
        <binding name="HttpAccessManagementService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.414.0" newVersion="5.0.414.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-16.1.0.0" newVersion="16.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Going crazy to solve this error and is that I did not add the report viewer in the toolbox? OR missing other .dll file instead of just "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" & "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" only?

Or just because all the publicKeyToken not same in assemblies for "Microsoft.Build.Framework" and "System.Web.Extensions.Design"?

Note: After i read some article, their mention that version 11 is for VS2012, still can use in VS2015?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Enterprise Layered Architecture,

When changing the .dll file for the UI.Web for version 11.00,
At the same also need to change the .dll file for the UI.Process.